# Visual Studio 2010, Clean Solution breaks references to other projects in solution

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, reference

Our company is planning to start a large new WinForm project, it will be written in c#-4.0 using Visual Studio 2010.

This project will have many modules (Production, Accounting, Service and etc...) and each module with have lots of possible forms. So we are testing the idea of create multiple projects inside a single solution and have each module be it's own project rather then having a single very large project.

I created a test solution with two projects **A** and **B**, next I added each project as a reference to the other project, when adding one project as a reference to the other, I right clicked on *Reference*>*Add Reference*>Browsed to the other projects *bin/Debug* folder and added the other project's *.exe* as the reference. Next, using the other project as a namespace I was able to do things like form inheritance and opening forms or calling methods between my two test projects.

But I accidently clicked *Clean Solution* which cleaned the bin/Debug folder for my two projects, and all of my references between the two projects were broken.

What is a proper and reliable way to add permanently references between projects inside a single solution? I was thinking I could physically copy each project's .exe into the other projects bin, then add it as a reference. But that means I'll have to manually re-copy it every time the other project get's updated.

Comment: It sounds like you have a circular dependency between A and B. Am I reading that right? If so, i would try to try to change the design. For example, you could factor out the shared code into project C and have both A and B depend on C.

Comment: @ama1111 I'm thinking you might be correct, but that will cause some issues with what we are trying to achieve in this project. Basically every project in this solutions needs to be able to call or start any of the other projects in the solution. If I don't manually add a reference, how can I call or start the entry form in the other project?

Comment: If you only need to start an executable B from A then you won't need to add a reference. However, if you need to instantiate and show a form defined in B from A then that would require a reference, in which case you'll have circular dependencies which you'll need to avoid. In that case you could consider including all of those in the same project and finding another way to organize the code into "modules" (such as folders, namespaces, etc.).

Comment: Ahh! Now were getting somewhere! I wasn't aware I could start the exe of the projects inside my solution without having a reference to them. That should solve my issues, first I have to figure out how to launch the other project's exe, then I'll do some more testing.

Comment: [Here's](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s.aspx) some documentation on how to start a process.